# Cube not showing in query designer in BIDS or Excel 2007

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I Have a few cubes in SSAS. All cubes are shown in Analysis Services in SQL Management Studio, but in Excel (2007) and Report Designer (SSRS in BIDS), one of them does not show.

Current user is Administrator so I have full access.

I don't know what the problem is? I would appreciate if someone explain what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

The Cube was hidden.Visible of the Cube was false.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing and re-opening Excel and BIDS.  They both cache metadata about cubes.

Comment: Thank's ,I do this work Several times ,but the problem still remains!